# How to remove fd's associated with a single socket from epoll instance?

Tags: epoll

I want to remove all file descriptors added to an epoll instance generated by accept() calls on a single socket. How can I do that without closing the epoll instance. Help please

Answer (score 0):

Use [`epoll_ctl`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/epoll_ctl) to modify the epoll instance:

```
epoll_ctl(instance_fd, EPOLL_CTL_DEL, fd_to_remove, &epoll_event);
```

Comment: How can I get the fd's from epoll instance which are not ready? As part of the server closing procedure, I need to close() all the file descriptors that it created through accept() call on a single socket.

Comment: It doesn't look like there's an API to get the list of fd's in an epoll instance. The application needs to keep track of these itself. If the server is shutting down, everything will be closed when the process exits, why do you need a list?